# Is there a way to deserialize the java object via python

Tags: java, python, serialization, hbase, deserialization

I stored the java object in hbase (i.e) Let's say I have an object 'User' with 3 parameters like firstname, middlename and lastname. I used the following code for serialization in java

```
Object object = (object) user;    
byte[] byteData = SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) object);
```

and stored in hbase like 'storing complete object (in byte[] format of above) in the Value portion of the KeyValue pair'

It is stored in hbase like (Example)

column=container:container, timestamp=1480016194005, value=\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00&com.test.container\x07\x89\x83\xFA\x7F\xD0F\xA5\x02\x00\x08I\x00\x07classIdJ\x00\x14dateTimeInLongFormatZ\x00\x04rootZ\x00\x09undefinedL\x00\x03keyt\x00\x12Ljava/lang/String;L\x00\x04modeq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x04nameq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x06userIdq\x00~\x00\x01xp\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x01X\x967\xBA\xF0\x00\x00t\x00\x1Econtainer_393_5639181044834024t\x00\x06expandt\x00\x02ert\x00\x08testadmin

when I try to retrieve the data, I used the following deserialization in java and converted back to object of readable format

object = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);

```
I would like to retrieve the data stored in java format via happybase using python and I achieved it and received the data as available in hbase like
```

It is stored in hbase like (Example)

column=container:container, timestamp=1480016194005, value=\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00&com.test.container\x07\x89\x83\xFA\x7F\xD0F\xA5\x02\x00\x08I\x00\x07classIdJ\x00\x14dateTimeInLongFormatZ\x00\x04rootZ\x00\x09undefinedL\x00\x03keyt\x00\x12Ljava/lang/String;L\x00\x04modeq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x04nameq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x06userIdq\x00~\x00\x01xp\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x01X\x967\xBA\xF0\x00\x00t\x00\x1Econtainer_393_5639181044834024t\x00\x06expandt\x00\x02ert\x00\x08testadmin

Is there a way to deserialize the java object via python

Thanks Much

Hari

Comment: Short answer: if you're asking this question then no. Longer answer: the Java binary serialization format is [well specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) so you could write code in Python, or any language, to read the data. But you obviously cannot create the same _behaviour_ in Python code an in Java code so whilst you can read the **data** from the serialized format, you cannot read the **behaviour**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a Python library for that:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javaobj-py3/

Usage seems pretty easy with:

```
import javaobj
jobj = self.read_file("obj5.ser")
pobj = javaobj.loads(jobj)
print(pobj)
```

Comment: By using `pyobj = javaobj.loads(data)` I am converting `b""` to object but sometimes I am getting error `RuntimeError: Stream has been ended unexpectedly while unmarshaling.`. Do you know any reason?

Comment: I'm getting error on read_file;  This method is not defined. What am I missing?

Comment: That method doesn't exist in Python, you will have to define it yourself