# Is there a way to deserialize the java object via python?

Tags: python

I have a java-serialized stream.
I want to deserialize it using python.

I tried solving this using the following link:
[Is there a way to deserialize the java object via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809062/is-there-a-way-to-deserialize-the-java-object-via-python)

Code suggested in the above link:

```
import javaobj    
import self

jobj = self.read_file("obj5.ser")
pobj = javaobj.loads(jobj)
print(pobj)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
module 'self' has no attribute 'read_file'
```

Please suggest if I can modify above code or if can use something else.

Comment: Have you tried to leave out the import of `self`? This would be the exact code from the other question and the example code on the website of `javaobj`.

Comment: Hi, just checked. It is now giving error:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Using self would imply that you are calling the function from inside a class.

**Edit:**
As an alternative you can use Unmarshaller object directly:

```
import javaobj

with open("objCollections.ser") as fobj : 
    marshaller = javaobj.JavaObjectUnmarshaller(fobj)
    pobj = marshaller.readObject()
```

As you can see in the docs:

> https://pypi.org/project/javaobj-py3/

Comment: I would recommend to use a context manager for the file object. Otherwise no one knows when the object is closed... `with open("objCollections.ser") as fobj : marshaller = javaobj.JavaObjectUnmarshaller(fobj)`